# Python mkdir() 'No Such FIle or Directory' w/ NodeJS

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mkdir, python-os

I have the following very simple Python program. When I run it by itself, it makes a new dir exactly as expected:

```
import os
os.mkdir("//myuncpath.com/folder1/newFolderName")     //makes new folder in remote file store location
```

So, I wrote a NodeJS app that simply calls this Python script:

```
const {PythonShell} = require("python-shell");

let options = {
    scriptPath: '/path/to/PyFile',
};

PythonShell.run('PythonFile.py', options, function (err, results) {     //calls .py file to mkdir
    if err: console.log(err);
})
```

However, when I call the script through Node, the Python script throws a FIleNotFound error:

```
{ Error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//myuncpath.com/folder1/newFolderName'
    at PythonShell.parseError
    ----- Python Traceback -----
    File "/location/to/PyFile.py", line 10, in <module>
        os.mkdir(sys.argv[1])
  traceback: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/location/to/PyFile.py", 
        line 10, in <module>\n    os.mkdir(my_dir)\nFileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: \'//myuncpath.com/folder1/newFolderName\'\n',
  executable: 'python3',
  options: null,
  script: '/location/to/PyFile.py',
  exitCode: 1 }
```

What seems to be going on here? I'm having a hard time decoding the traceback from Python because everything looks somewhat normal to me (apart from maybe some weird \n's an \' around the path maybe?)

Also, if I replace the os.mkdir in the Python with just a `print("Hello")`, that works fine, so the script is being called right, it just doesn't like the os.mdkir

I'd appreciate any help at all, I've been stuck on this for weeks now.

Comment: are they both on the same os?

Comment: Is it possible that in your first try `folder1` was exists but later was not?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the user identity that you're running the code in. When you run the Python script, presumably you're running it as a user who has access to the target path. But when you're calling it through Node, what user context is the NodeJS app running at? If that user doesn't have access to the target path, the Python script won't be able to find the target directory to create the new directory in. Things to try:

- Run NodeJS in the same user context as you were using to run the Python script
- Give the NodeJS user account permission to access the target path.

Comment: Now that you say it this seems very very plausible. Is there any way to add my credentials that have access to the UNC path into the Python file? even if they're hardcoded?

Comment: It would depend on the OS. If the Python script is running on Windows, you could use the win32security functions LogonUser and ImpersonateLoggedOnUser to set up a specific user context. On Unix-like systems, os.setuid would do the job - but on Linux setuid scripts are not allowed, so you have to 'wrap' them in a compiled program such as contemplated here:

https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/setuid-prog.c

It might be simpler in the end to figure out the user context that NodeJS is running it and grant read/write permissions to that in the target directory.